# How can I change the text of my Button from my TimePickerFragment class?

Tags: java, android

I started experimenting with time and date pickers in Andrioid.

My classes are as follows:

Main.java

```
package com.valgriz.testapplication2;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.Spinner;

 public class Main extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener,
    OnItemSelectedListener {
Button bPickTime;
Button bPickDate;
Spinner sTime;
TimePickerFragment tpf;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    bPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPickTime);
    bPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPickDate);
    sTime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sTime);
    bPickTime.setOnClickListener(this);
    bPickDate.setOnClickListener(this);
    sTime.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter sAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.sChoices1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    sAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sTime.setAdapter(sAdapter);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.bPickTime) {
        DialogFragment df = new TimePickerFragment();
        df.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePickerFragment");

    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.bPickDate) {
        DialogFragment df = new DatePickerFragment();
        df.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePickerFragment");
    }
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int selection,
        long identification) {

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}

 }
```

TimePickerFragment.java

```
 package com.valgriz.testapplication2;

 import java.util.Calendar;

 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
 import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
 import android.text.format.DateFormat;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TimePicker;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
    OnTimeSetListener {
int hourOfDay;
int minute;

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hourOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hourOfDay, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

}
 }
```

How can I set the text of bPickTime to be the hour and minute of the day?
so the button will look like this "hourOfDay + ":" + minute"

Thanks,

-Steve

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the button is in some layout file eg. `main.xml`. To access the view of any layout file that you haven't set using `setContentView()`, you need to **inflate** that particular layout and then access it's view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Now you can use that `button` however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize the `Button` in `TimePickerFragment.java` exactly like you did in `Main.java`, then use

```
bPickTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
```

Comment: I am unable to do that, I believe because TimePickerFragment.java does not extend an activity